# convert png to gif with gdi+ (C#)

Tags: c#, gdi+

i have a png file which must be converted to a gif file.
There is a transparent part in it, and when i save it the transparent part is black in stead of transparent.
here's my code:

```
FileStream imgStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

Image.FromFile(imageInput).Save(imgStream, ImageFormat.Gif);
```

here, imageinput is the fullpath to my png, and output file is the filefullpath with .gif extension.

can you see what is wrong here?

michel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PNG uses alpha transparency, meaning that each pixel, in addition to its color, also contains a value denoting how transparent it is (called `alpha`).  This allows PNG images to be semi-transparent.

GIF images use binary transparency, meaning that each pixel only contains a color, but one of the possible colors is `Transparent`.

Therefore, the transparent parts of the PNG will be colored black, but completely transparent.
When you save the GIF file, the alpha value is ignored, resulting in black.

<strike>You need to loop through the pixels in the image, replacing any color which has an alpha of 0 with `Color.Transparent`.</strike>

**EDIT**: You need to call [`MakeTransparent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Now the transparent color is shown as white... when i do Color.Orange all transparent pixels are shown orange, but when i do Color.Transparent all transparent pixels are shown white. Can it be a problem that a lot of the pixels are white? Or should i 'say' which color should be used to be the transparent one?

Comment: looking in intellisense learned that color.transparent is actually white? is there a way to make the transparent color for example green and say to the gif 'green must be transparent'?

Answer (score 3):

As other posters have pointed out, GIF doesn't support alpha transparency--but a single color in the GIF can be set as fully-transparent. You could convert the PNG to a 256-color paletted bitmap and replace any fully-transparent (A = 255) to `Colors.Transparent`, and then save the new image as a GIF.

See `ImageAttributes` and `ColorMap` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The GIF image format does not support alpha transparency.

- GIF supports 24-bit RGB.
- PNG supports 32-bit RGBA.

The A is used to specify transparency and
I would imagine the converter ignores the A value.

[PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

[GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format)

Comment: what do you mean by that? is transparent in png something else than transparent in gif?