# How can I save a gif with a transparent background?

Tags: c#, .net, gif

I have an app that allows users to create simple images that are no more than text with a desired background color.  The users can select a color from a `System.Windows.Forms.ColorDialog` and use it to set the text color and the background color.

The background color can be set to transparent (I use `Color.Transparent` as the reference for the transparency) and after selection, I update the preview image which displays the text and the transparency correctly.  However, when I go to save the image, I can not get the transparency to save with the image as a gif.

I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989450/convert-png-to-gif-with-gdi-c) which states that I should use the [`MakeTransparent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent.aspx) method to set the transaprency color.

Before I call the Save operation, I take the image that is in memory and redraw it using black as the background/transparent color and then before I save the image call the `MakeTransperent` method on the in-memory image.  Still, the image saves out with black as the background.

What might I be doing wrong?

---

EDIT: Here is the relevant code.

This is the method that creates the image.  The `overrideBG` variable is used to specify if we should set the transparency color to a non-alpha color for the gif.

```
void ReDrawImage(bool overrideBG = false) //My method that draws the image in memory.
{
    //My In Memory Image creation
    img = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(img);

    ...

    //This portion of code sets the BG color to what should be the transparency color, if the BG is transparent
    if (overrideBG)
        {
            gfx.Clear(TransparentColor); //TransparentColor = Black, unless Text Color is Black.  If so, it equals White.
        }
        else
        {
            gfx.Clear(BackColorPreview.BackColor);
        }

    //Followed by code that writes the text.
}

//This is the save method (Assume we are always drawing a transparent background.)
Save()
{
    ReDrawImage(true);
    img.MakeTransparent(TransparentColor); //I've also tried moving this line before the ReDrawImage call
    img.Save(SaveFile.FileName, ImageFormat.Gif);
    ReDrawImage();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently there are issues with `MakeTransparent` and gifs. I found [this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20131202141039/http://www.codedblog.com/2007/08/28/generating-a-transparent-gif-image-using-c/) which provides and alternative by way of modifying the image bytes in memory. Here's the code sample from the post with syntax errors fixed.

```
/// <summary>  
/// Returns a transparent background GIF image from the specified Bitmap.  
/// </summary>  
/// <param name="bitmap">The Bitmap to make transparent.</param>  
/// <param name="color">The Color to make transparent.</param>  
/// <returns>New Bitmap containing a transparent background gif.</returns>  
public static Bitmap MakeTransparentGif(Bitmap bitmap, Color color)
{
    byte R = color.R;
    byte G = color.G;
    byte B = color.B;
    MemoryStream fin = new MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(fin, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    MemoryStream fout = new MemoryStream((int)fin.Length);
    int count = 0;
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    byte transparentIdx = 0;
    fin.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    //header  
    count = fin.Read(buf, 0, 13);
    if ((buf[0] != 71) || (buf[1] != 73) || (buf[2] != 70)) return null; //GIF  
    fout.Write(buf, 0, 13);
    int i = 0;
    if ((buf[10] & 0x80) > 0)
    {
        i = 1 << ((buf[10] & 7) + 1) == 256 ? 256 : 0;
    }
    for (; i != 0; i--)
    {
        fin.Read(buf, 0, 3);
        if ((buf[0] == R) && (buf[1] == G) && (buf[2] == B))
        {
            transparentIdx = (byte)(256 - i);
        }
        fout.Write(buf, 0, 3);
    }
    bool gcePresent = false;
    while (true)
    {
        fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
        fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
        if (buf[0] != 0x21) break;
        fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
        fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
        gcePresent = (buf[0] == 0xf9);
        while (true)
        {
            fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
            fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
            if (buf[0] == 0) break;
            count = buf[0];
            if (fin.Read(buf, 0, count) != count) return null;
            if (gcePresent)
            {
                if (count == 4)
                {
                    buf[0] |= 0x01;
                    buf[3] = transparentIdx;
                }
            }
            fout.Write(buf, 0, count);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0)
    {
        count = fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
        fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
    }
    fin.Close();
    fout.Flush();
    return new Bitmap(fout);
}
```

I tried it with Hans' sample (replacing gif parts) and it works for me.

Your code would look like

```
img = MakeTransparent(img, TransparentColor); 
img.Save(SaveFile.FileName, ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Comment: This isn't the answer that I hoped for but it is the one that worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

GDI version 1.10 supports a property to store the transparency color, property ID 20740.  I see it getting used by the GIF encoder on Windows 7 with this test code:

```
        var bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
            gr.Clear(Color.Blue);
            gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 80, 80));
        }
        bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Red);
        bmp.Save(@"c:\temp\test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

This code properly restores the bitmap:

```
    private static Bitmap LoadGif(string path) {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(path);
        bool found = false;
        foreach (System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem item in bmp.PropertyItems) {
            if (item.Id == 20740) {
                int paletteIndex = item.Value[0];
                Color backGround = bmp.Palette.Entries[paletteIndex];
                bmp.MakeTransparent(backGround);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Property missing, punt at the color of the lower-left pixel
        //if (!found) bmp.MakeTransparent();
        return bmp;
    }
```

No idea if this will work on earlier versions of GDI+, I don't have XP anymore.  The SDK explicitly mentions version 1.10, first shipped with Vista.

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing, it's just that my process is split across multiple methods.  Also, I have no need to restore an image to the application.

Comment: I have no idea what that really means.  Whatever program you use to look at the image seems to not use the property item.  Try another one or write your own.

Comment: I create an image that is stored in memory which is displayed in a PictureBox. When the user Saves the image, I write the in-memory image (img) to a gif file. My process is exactly as you have outlined above in the first code sample, with the exception that I manipulate the image in my ReDrawImage method and I save the file in the Save method.

Comment: I tested the first code snippet on WinXP and it doesn't seem to work- I get a black square with a blue border viewing with chrome.

Comment: it does not work: `paletteIndex` is outofrange of `Palette.Entries[paletteIndex]`